# jquery accordion menu keep open

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I have such code for accordion menu

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine. When I click menu item which has children it slides down but after clicking child this menu doesnt keep open. I tried to add open class to active element but it doesnt work.

Comment: show your html or make a jsFiddle  please

Comment: Code is from here: http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/wordpress-accordion-menu-tutorial